# python import module vs running script as subprocess.popen

Tags: python, import, subprocess

Suppose I have python script having having 4-5 functions all are called from single function in a script. If I want to results after executing script( Use functions from another script)  I can make script executable and use subprocess.popen and I can also import these functions in another script. Which is better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is better way to do this?

Use `import` unless you have to use `subprocess.Popen` to run Python code.

- `import` uses `sys.path` to find the module; you don't need to specify the path explicitly
- usually, imported functions accept arguments, return results in the same process; you don't need to serialize Python objects into bytes to send them to another process

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use functions from an other script then you usually import the script.

When the script is `script.py` you can write `import script` and use the functions that are defined in the script with `script.function_in_the_script`.

Comment: I would like to know which is better when you can achieve same functionality by "subprocess.popen" : executable py script  or  "import" python function